# Como criar uma procedure que acesse uma substring e calcular usando a substring como parâmetro?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso criar uma procedure que de acordo com a substring de um título, calcular a média dos preços dos livros com a substring passada como parâmetro, e a média dos preços precisa ser um parâmetro de saída

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE TB_Autor(
   Cod_autor int primary key,
   Nome_autor varchar(40),
   Sexo char(1)
)

CREATE TABLE TB_Livro(
    Cod_livro  int primary key,
    Cod_autor int constraint FK_TB_Livro_Autor foreign key references TB_Autor(Cod_autor),
    Titulo_livro varchar(40),
    Genero_livro varchar(20),
    Valor_livro money
)

CREATE TABLE TB_Cliente(
    Cod_cliente int primary key,
    Nome_cliente varchar(50),
    Data_nascimento date,
    Sexo char(1)
)


CREATE TABLE TB_Cidade(
    Cod_municipio int primary key,
    Nome_municipio varchar(30),
    UF char(2),
    Região char(20)
)

CREATE TABLE TB_Venda(
    Cod_venda int primary key,
    Cod_livro int constraint FK_TB_Venda_Livro foreign key references TB_Livro(Cod_livro),
    Cod_cliente int constraint FK_TB_Venda_Cliente foreign key references TB_Cliente(Cod_cliente),
    Cod_municipio int constraint FK_TB_Venda_Cidade foreign key references TB_Cidade(Cod_municipio),
    Qtd_venda int,
    Valor_venda money,
    Data_venda date
)
```

A procedure abaixo é o que eu tenho, não sei como fazer funcionar

```
create procedure sp_exL @livro varchar(50)
as
begin
select AVG(valor_livro) as 'Media'  from TB_Livro
where titulo_livro like %@livro%
end 

exec sp_exL 'Livro'
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem. Dê um exemplo de dados nas tabelas, uma entrada de exemplo e saída desejada para esta entrada

Comment: Acrescente um segundo parâmetro na declaração do procedimento, mas com a tag OUTPUT.  Pronto, você já tem seu parâmetro de saída.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente:

```
-- código #1
CREATE PROCEDURE exL 
     @livro varchar(50),
     @pMedia money output
as
begin
set nocount on;
set @pMedia= (SELECT avg (valor_livro) from TB_Livro
              where titulo_livro like '%' + @livro + '%');
end;
go
```

Não testei; pode conter erro(s).

---

Para usar:

```
-- código #2
declare @pesq varchar(20), @valor_médio money;

set @pesq= 'raia';
EXECUTE exL @livro= @pesq, @pMedia= @valor_médio output;

SELECT @valor_médio;
```